# Whatsapp Last Seen/Online Info No longer available under Contact Info

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

It has been a few days I noticed that I can't see whatsapp Online/Last Seen on User's Profile page.
Old Image:[image: Whatsapp UI Showing Online Status of User]

But there's Nothing like this in Current Version of Whatsapp... Anyone knows any reason for this Change/Update? Or it is happening to me only (Coz I didn't find any post about this Change anywhere on Internet)?

Comment: Looks like it's not only you, but I'm not sure we can find the reason for this change if WhatsApp didn't mention anything.

Comment: Maybe this [new feature](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.livemint.com/technology/tech-news/whatsapp-to-release-important-update-related-to-hide-last-seen-check-details/amp-11631233072392.html&ved=2ahUKEwiGz9q8s4_zAhXDdHAKHQvmCZ8QFnoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3IzP2mruVaSx0yqx6Lc1Em&ampcf=1) of Whatsapp is being used by your contact?